# HTML5 Wysiwyg simple "Image editor" add text

Tags: html, image, canvas

i am searching code or a Html5 Wysiwyg image editor which is capaple of the following:

- Wysiwyg add overlay text to image

I think this could easiestly be handled by canvas and html5. the source most likely would be a data_uri so that the creation of the final picture can be done by create canvas. The conversion into real file is accessible by any programming language.

My idea is:

1. Create Canvas as data_uri out of Picture (physical file)
2. being able to 2a) write text within a drawn overlay, 2b) place and resize that overlay whereever you want on the created Canvas

Is there anything doing this or will it be possible with which code?

Comment: So you want to know if you can copy a img from an url to canvas and add text to the canvas and then download the canvas as img ?

Comment: @dwana the download isn't the problem since it is natively accessible. problem is the wysiwyg editor (place, resize text box in wysiwyg mode). the writing could be done with fillText, but the POSITION SHALL BE DYNAMICALLY to the users input wysiwyg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scaling an image of text often results in undesireable pixilation.

**Alternatively, here is an annotated example that lets the user:**

1. Enter a text into a text-input.
2. Click a button to fillText that text onto the canvas.
3. Use mouse events to "drag" the text around the canvas.

**About Resizing:**

You could add another set of 2 html buttons that let the user scale the text larger or smaller. Rather than scaling an image of the text, you could simply increase or decrease the font size in response to the html buttons.

**Demo:**

```js
// canvas related variables
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

// variables used to get mouse position on the canvas
var $canvas=$("#canvas");
var canvasOffset=$canvas.offset();
var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;
var scrollX=$canvas.scrollLeft();
var scrollY=$canvas.scrollTop();

// variables to save last mouse position
// used to see how far the user dragged the mouse
// and then move the text by that distance
var startX;
var startY;

// an array to hold text objects
var texts=[];

// this var will hold the index of the hit-selected text
var selectedText=-1;

// clear the canvas & redraw all texts
function draw(){
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  for(var i=0;i<texts.length;i++){
    var text=texts[i];
    ctx.fillText(text.text,text.x,text.y);
  }
}

// test if x,y is inside the bounding box of texts[textIndex]
function textHittest(x,y,textIndex){
  var text=texts[textIndex];
  return(x>=text.x && 
         x<=text.x+text.width &&
         y>=text.y-text.height && 
         y<=text.y);
}

// handle mousedown events
// iterate through texts[] and see if the user
// mousedown'ed on one of them
// If yes, set the selectedText to the index of that text
function handleMouseDown(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  startX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  startY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
  // Put your mousedown stuff here
  for(var i=0;i<texts.length;i++){
    if(textHittest(startX,startY,i)){
      selectedText=i;
    }
  }
}

// done dragging
function handleMouseUp(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  selectedText=-1;
}

// also done dragging
function handleMouseOut(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  selectedText=-1;
}

// handle mousemove events
// calc how far the mouse has been dragged since
// the last mousemove event and move the selected text
// by that distance
function handleMouseMove(e){
  if(selectedText<0){return;}
  e.preventDefault();
  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  // Put your mousemove stuff here
  var dx=mouseX-startX;
  var dy=mouseY-startY;
  startX=mouseX;
  startY=mouseY;

  var text=texts[selectedText];
  text.x+=dx;
  text.y+=dy;
  draw();
}

// listen for mouse events
$("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
$("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
$("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});
$("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseOut(e);});

$("#submit").click(function(){

  // calc the y coordinate for this text on the canvas
  var y=texts.length*20+20;

  // get the text from the input element
  var text={text:$("#theText").val(),x:20,y:y};

  // calc the size of this text for hit-testing purposes
  ctx.font="16px verdana";
  text.width=ctx.measureText(text.text).width;
  text.height=16;

  // put this new text in the texts array
  texts.push(text);

  // redraw everything
  draw();

});
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
#theText{width:10em;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="theText" type="text">
<button id="submit">Draw text on canvas then drag it</button><br>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```